# Haskell and Data.Array.//: why is this type correct?

Tags: haskell

Creating a two-dimensional array:

```
import Data.Array
arr = listArray ((1, 1), (10, 10)) [1..]  -- :: (Ix i, Num i, Num e, Enum e) => Array i e
```

`//` can be used to update a value. You need to provide a list of tuples with an index and a value. Since our index is a two-tuple, the type needs to be `[((a, b), e)]`.

```
 arr // _  -- _ :: [((a, b), e)]
```

Now I used `[(1, 999)]` by accident to update the first value. Of course it should have been `[((1,1), 999)]`. However, the mistake turned out to be type-correct!

```
 arr2 = arr // [(1, 999)]
 arr2  -- :: (Ix a, Ix b, Enum e, Num a, Num b, Num e, Num (a, b)) => Array (a, b) e
```

It hangs when I try to evaluate `arr2`, but I still wonder why this is type correct.

Comment: I wish GHC produced a warning when failing to resolve a `Num (t a1 ... an)` constraint where, `t` is one of the standard prelude constructors. Something like "this type is unlikely to be a numeric type, and this can cause type errors later on". The chance that such types will eventually turn out to be numeric ones is negligible in practice. OTOH, this is another reason why type signatures should always be added, generating errors as early as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is buried in the type signature you quoted. It's this part:

```
Num (a, b)
```

Haskell type class instances have an "open world" assumption. The compiler doesn't know you're not going to define an `instance Num (a, b)` (or the same instance with constraints on `a` and/or `b`) in another module that you import. As soon as you do, then `[(1, 9999)]` has the correct type, because `1`, like all integer literals, has type `(Num t) => t`, in other words it can be of any type for which there exists an instance of `Num`. If you make an `instance Num (a, b)` (or similar) then, as strange as it may look at first sight, it's perfectly correct to say that `1` has type (or at least might have type) `(a, b)`.

Answer (score 5):

It says in the result type constraints `Num (a, b)`. That is, this is only type correct if a tuple of numbers is itself a number. Someone could write that instance, and if they did then `1` could be interpreted as a tuple to index into the array with.

Answer (score 4):

The type signature explains it:

```
arr2  -- :: (Ix a, Ix b, Enum e, Num a, Num b, Num e, Num (a, b)) => Array (a, b) e
```

It assumes that the tuple `(a, b)` is a `Num`ber as well (the `Num (a, b)` part). So it interpets `1` as a number literal that can be converted, with [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger), to a 2-tuple of type `(a, b)`, and thus will represent the index.

By default a 2-tuple is not an instance of `Num`. You can make a 2-tuple an instance of `Num`, but to what would `1` map here? If you thus later aim to obtain an array that is sensical, the type checker will not find what values to fill in for `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: Thanks (to everyone). `arr // [(1 :: Int, 999)]` is indeed NOT type correct. I get it now. :-)